# Multiple answer to anti spam ninja forms

Tags: wordpress, spam-prevention, ninja-forms

I have a contact form made in Ninja Forms and I have set an Anti-Spam question, "What is the number after four?". The answer is obviously "five" but what if the user uses uppercase letters or capitalized first letter (e.g Five, FIVE). Is possible for the anti-spam field to accept either of the 3 settings?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Ninja Forms, Rephrase your question like this:

> What is the number after 4?(Numeric)

I also suggest not using Ninja Form anti-spam field as protection, the question is static thus a bot can still create a lot of contact form applications.